# What does the "missing separator" make error mean when using Qt?

Tags: qt, makefile

I'm creating a simple Qt program, and when I run `make`, I get the following:

```
make -f Makefile.Debug
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/gotocell'
Makefile.Debug:59: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/gotocell'
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

What do those errors mean? And, if `make` proceeds correctly, what output should I expect (i.e. `.exe`)?

The contents of the `.pro` file is as follows:

**EDIT** added `target`

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Sun Sep 9 08:26:50 2012
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = gotocell.exe
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
FORMS += gotocelldialog.ui
```

**EDIT**

After modifying the target in `.pro`, I get the following:

```
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile gotocell.pro
make -f Makefile.Debug
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/gotocell'
Makefile.Debug:59: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/gotocell'
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Comment: It means the makefile has a bug. How did you generate it? Could you show your `.pro` file?

Comment: @Mat. I used `qmake`. The `.pro` file contains the following: `######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Sun Sep 9 08:26:50 2012
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
FORMS += gotocelldialog.ui
`

Comment: Could you put the contents of .pro in your question?

Comment: Your target is empty. Target is the name of your final application (e.g. MyApplication.exe). You also don't have SOURCES and HEADERS field.

Comment: @ Aleksandar. I'm really new to this. How can I add SOURCES and HEADERS?

Comment: If you use QtCreator then they will be automatically added. If you don't then open the .pro and copy paste my answer's code into it. You will of course need to create main.cpp mainWindow.cpp and mainWindow.hpp. I will try to find you a good Qt tutorial.

Comment: Zetcode always provided good examples. Here is one for qt : http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/

Comment: Usually, this error means an incorrect use of tab characters.

Comment: Please show a few lines of Makefile.Debug, from line 59 and a few lines before and after, that will help to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Missing separator errors occur when the project failed to configure well.

Check your .pro file and see what qmake outputs.

Here is an example of .pro file that should generate a good Makefile

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Sun Sep 9 08:26:50 2012
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = myapp # I think that .exe is not neccessary
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

SOURCES = main.cpp mainWindow.cpp
HEADERS = mainWindow.hpp

# Input
FORMS += gotocelldialog.ui
```

Answer (score 1):

I have meet the same question. 
And I use the "Qt 4.8.4 Command Prompt" provided by qt.
Then I use "qmake -project", "qmake", "nmake", "debug/hello.exe" in this terminal. 
It's ok.
Good luck with you :)